# Алгоритм метод итераций(метод последовательных приближений)

Tags: c++

как сделать приведение к виду x = f(x) в методе простых итераций, если функция имеет вид 3*x-1=cos(x) ? Помогите пожалуйста...

Comment: @Harry Откуда мы взяли вот ето 
return ((2*x-2)*x*x-36)/((3*x-4)*x-15);
return ((x-2)*x-15)*x+36;
?

Comment: Получили так, как в ответе показано. Второй - это, собственно, заданная функция, первый - приведенная... Очевидно, что в вашем случае f(x), которая вам нужна, равна x-(3x-1-cos(x))/(3+sin(x)) - там же все ясно написано.